# Getting action from button created dynamically

Tags: jakarta-ee

i am using a jsp page in which i am trying to show all emailID from database and with every emailID a delete button attached to it like-

```
                <table border=0>
                <% 
                   while(rs.next())
                   {
                %>
                <tr>
                <td><h3><font color="blue"><b><%=rs.getString("emailID") %> 
                </b>
                </font></h3></td>
                <td width="70%"></td>
                <td><h3
                ><input type="submit" value="delete"></h3></td> 
                </tr>

                <%
                }
                %>
                </table>
```

in ResultSet i have emailID. I want to implement a code that can delete an emailID whenever its corresponding delete button is been clicked.The problem what i am facing is that i am not able to differentiate between different buttons.On what basis should i compare two buttons that will perform different functions.As the buttons are dynamically created how can i delete a particular record with particular button.The already given answer is only for one button while i am dealing for many of them. Please specify some correct code. Thanks

Comment: i want answer for my context please :) That is by using javascript. i am not using that

Comment: anyone?? Please!